# Should we separate the aspects and tenses in tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Taking a look at tags, we have [perfect-aspect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perfect-aspect) and [past-tense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/past-tense) (<s>hell, we have [past](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/past) too, probably created by mistake</s>) and we also have [present-perfect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/present-perfect) and [past-perfect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/past-perfect).

On one hand, classifying tenses like *[tense aspect] tense* is one of the commoner [grammar-myths](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar-myths); and on the other hand many learners may only be familiar with this kind of classification.

Should we have tags focusing on one aspect or tense or do we prefer the likes of the non-existent [present-perfect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/present-perfect) "tense" as our tags?

Comment: Shouldn't "tense" be enough? I think so.

Comment: Certainly not @Usernew! We have a lot of questions revolving around the subtleties of using aspects; "tense" is not terribly helpful.

Comment: hmmm.. that's something I overlooked. LOL :(

Comment: [tag:past] can (and should) be blacklisted; as I write this there are no longer any questions with that tag.

Comment: Gotcha @Stoney! What about the others?

Comment: Gimme a chance, dude; I'm working on it.

Comment: In the (American) schools I went to, the grammar instruction (and introductory foreign language instruction) taught about "past tense", "present tense", "future tense", "progressive", "infinitive", "gerund", and *maybe* "past participle".  "Hypotheticals" and "subjunctive" were discussed at some point, but in nowhere near the detail that it has been taught to many learners on this site.  I don't remember whether the concept of "aspect" was taught at all.  Therefore, I don't think it is reasonable to expect native speakers to distinguish between tense and "aspect".

Comment: The tags are starting to distinguish between concepts that many users (both native speakers and learners) are not familiar with.  Good tag wikis would be especially helpful when explaining these concepts.

Comment: @Jasper You can't really expect native speakers to deal with *any* grammar terminology, though.  The few things we learn in schools, we learn poorly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't object too strenuously to *past-tense* and *present-tense*; though in my universe these aren't tenses but forms, there's a lot to be said for keeping the lines of communication open between the Young Turks and the Mustache Petes. *Future-tense* is more problematic, and I really dislike *progressive-aspect* and *perfect-aspect*; these again aren't aspects but constructions.

But really, are we going to get anywhere shuffling deck-tags on the Titanic? There's just too much overlap between tags and categories for there to be any hope of redeeming this random and corrupt system bottom-up, with local fixes and adjustments. Here's a (somewhat) organized list of the 80 tags we're dealing with around just verbs, with their use counts:

[image: Verb tags on ELL]

That's just tag salad. To my mind, what we should be doing is designing a good **system** of tags, and then do what it takes to implement that.

Comment: I think it's time we create a list of tags and sort the bad ones out, and create tags on the go. What do you think?