# Is This Tag Useful? Episode 2 -- The Twins (usage and meaning)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleaning

The argument for getting rid of these tags is going to be much more straightforward.

We have tags like [phrase-meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-meaning), [meaning-in-context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context), [sentence-meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-meaning) etc. just like we have the likes of [word-usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage) and [phrase-usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-usage), the usability of which is still questionable but that's not the point of this post.

So, we already have divided [meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) and [usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) into other tags and having both set of tags is redundant and annoying. We have two options if we want to get out of this [tag salad](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2835/14111): Either let the broader or the narrower tags be.

In my opinion, *which is to be proven wrong or right*, the division still has resulted in very broad tags: One learner may be confused by the cultural nuances bound to a fixed expression and use [phrase-meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-meaning); a second learner might be baffled by a possible variation between the meanings given by dictionaries for a phrase and still use [phrase-meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-meaning).

What I'm saying is, when my pen gets lost in a van, do we want to keep it in a truck? Do we want to get rid of [meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) and [usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage)?

If so,

- If you're an **editor** or a **tagger**, I humbly request you make sure you edit out [[grammar]](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2699/is-this-tag-useful-episode-1-the-big-boss-grammar), [meaning], and [usage] whenever you edit a post.
- If you're an **asker** who sees this meta post, please do **not** add [usage] and [meaning] to your question. Decide what kind of thing you're seeking the meaning or the usage for. And if you're desperate to choose a tag, choose [grammar] and we'll figure it out!